# AttributeError: 'FrozenImporter' object has no attribute 'filename'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, plotly-dash

I keep getting the following error when running the exe file generated from plotly-dash codes using PyInstaller.

```
AttributeError: 'FrozenImporter' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

Did some in-depth check, only able to identify the attribute error happened when dash is trying to ***import dash_renderer*** and retrieving the filename from the line ***package.filename***

Tried adding the following but still unable to resolve

1. added **import dash_renderer** to my codes
2. copied dash and dash_renderer package folders into dist/{app}/ folder

My plotly-dash codes

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H2(children='H-{} Meeting Dashboard'.format("SS"), style={'text-align':'center'}),
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Div('''Generated on {}'''.format(str(datetime.now())[:19]), style={'text-align':'center', 'font-size':'15px'})
        ], className='row')]
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

PyInstaller Codes used to generate the exe file

```
\path\to\python37\python.exe -m PyInstaller app_short.py
```

Error when running the .exe file, run into error below

```
my\directory>app_short.exe
2019-06-25 23:36:55 Imported all modules
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_short.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1476, in run_server
  File "site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1361, in enable_dev_tools
  File "site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1359, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'FrozenImporter' object has no attribute 'filename'
[16716] Failed to execute script app_short
```

Running the app_short.py file was able to launch the flask app properly and the html page could be access, but the exe kept showing AttributeError.

```
\my\directory>app_short.py
2019-06-25 23:56:47 Imported all modules
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 313-047-004
 * Serving Flask app "app_short" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
2019-06-25 23:56:51 Imported all modules
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 074-068-565
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same error message, and I resolved it by changing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Not sure why this happens or if running with `debug=False` is even possible for your needs! Maybe someone else can elaborate?

Comment: apparently, the required folders for dash is left out during pyinstaller compilation.
by adding the following folders to the post compilation does the job. dash_core_components , dash_html_components and dash_renderer

Comment: But then you cannot use debug mode.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914106/pyinstaller-error-when-executing-plotly-dash-exec-file) are also some examples

Answer (score -2):

```
app.run_server(debug=False)
```

The development tools are typically used during development for debugging and shouldn't be necessary for a production executable.