# PyInstaller not reading imported module in dist

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Update: I'm an idiot. Needed to switch the '-' to '_' in the 'dash-uploader' part.

I'm trying to make an executable from my Python script with PyInstaller. I haven't had an issue so far, but in my newest version I'm using the dash-uploader library and PyInstaller is not detecting it. I've tried using --hidden-import and --additional-hook-dir but haven't had any luck.

The closest I've gotten to it working is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63478278/15180899) solution with `datas=[('C:\\Users\\<Name>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\dash_uploader', 'dash-uploader'),],` in my .spec file, which does end up creating a dash-uploader folder in my dist folder (which the other methods didn't do), but it keeps throwing this error when I try to run the exe: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<Name>\\EXE-TEST\\dist\\AvPlotter\\dash_uploader\\_build\\package-info.json'` However, the package-info.json *is* there. Any suggestions on why this isn't working/how to make pyinstaller see this file?

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to the command line:

```
--collect-data "dash_uploader"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, I'm still getting the same error.